# How do I obtain Kubernetes CA Certificate?

Tags: kubernetes, x509certificate, hashicorp-vault

I am setting up Vault in Kubernetes and enabling the Kubernetes Auth method. It needs the Kubernetes CA Certificate. How do I obtain that? I couldn't find much on duckduckgo's search results.

[image]

Running kubernetes inside Docker for mac on MacOS Mojave:

[image]
Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

This can be found in your `kube-system` (or any other) namespace by running the following on your `default-token` secret:

```
kubectl get secret <secret name> -n <namespace> -o jsonpath="{['data']['ca\.crt']}" | base64 --decode
```

To find the `secret name` run `kubectl get secret -n kube-system` and find the secret that starts with `default-token`.

This will give you something like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXXXXXX
XXXX....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

When you are entering this certificate, make sure to enter the BEGIN and END header and footer.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the "get secret" way is not working anymore (from [the release 1.24 there aren't auto-generated secrets](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.24.md#urgent-upgrade-notes)).

In GKE clusters, I've found this way to get the ca certificate:

```bash
kubectl get cm kube-root-ca.crt -o jsonpath="{['data']['ca\.crt']}"
```

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl get cm -o jsonpath='{.items[0].data.ca\.crt}' | tr -d '\n'`